# How to have multiple conditions for one if statement in python

Tags: python, function, if-statement, arguments, conditional-statements

So I am writing some code in python 3.1.5 that requires there be more than one condition for something to happen. Example:

```
def example(arg1, arg2, arg3):
    if arg1 == 1:
        if arg2 == 2:
            if arg3 == 3:
                print("Example Text")
```

The problem is that when I do this it doesn't print anything if arg2 and arg3 are equal to anything but 0. Help?

Comment: how about `if (arg1, arg2, arg3) == (1, 2, 3):`

Comment: "The problem is that when I do this it doesn't print anything if arg2 and arg3 are equal to anything but 0" - expected. Seems like the only working argument here is 1,2,3

Comment: why not `if arg1 == 1 and arg2 == 2 and arg3 == 3:` ?

Comment: Roberto I already tried that one but ozgur I will try yours

Comment: @SooBaccaCole it should have worked... I really don't see why not, sorry.

Comment: ozgur yours didnt work improper syntax. Should i mention i use Ninja IDE?

Comment: Actually roberto yours does work i just typed it in wrong sorry about that

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I would use

```
def example(arg1, arg2, arg3):
     if arg1 == 1 and arg2 == 2 and arg3 == 3:
          print("Example Text")
```

The `and` operator is identical to the logic gate with the same name; it will return 1 if and only if all of the inputs are 1. You can also use `or` operator if you want that logic gate.

EDIT: Actually, the code provided in your post works fine with me. I don't see any problems with that. I think that this might be a problem with your Python, not the actual language.

Comment: My IDE said there was no syntax or other errors with it but when it runs it doesn't output the text properly. Roberto and your code, (which are one and the same,) both worked fine.

Answer (score 43):

Darian Moody has a nice solution to this challenge in his [blog post](https://www.djm.org.uk/posts/python-multiple-line-conditions-and-all-builtin/):

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = True

rules = [a == 1,
         b == 2,
         c == True]

if all(rules):
    print("Success!")
```

The all() method returns `True` when all elements in the given iterable are true. If not, it returns `False`.

You can read a *little* more about it in the python docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#all) and more information and examples [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/all).

(I also answered the similar question with this info here - [How to have multiple conditions for one if statement in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36757965/how-to-have-multiple-conditions-for-one-if-statement-in-python/50656647#50656647))

Comment: This is extremely useful when distinguishing multiple and statements that are independent from each-other by an or! Thank you for this!

Comment: Thanks @nikooters! I could not agree more; it fit my needs exactly...the need that brought me to this questions. Cheers!

Comment: Note that there is no short-circuiting with this approach - all conditions are always evaluated. In a regular 'if' condition with 'and's, python would stop evaluating once it encountered the first false condition.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I spent several hours finding this simplified solution. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi @Akif, Thank you. Are there particular terms that we can add to this to help others find this answer easier?

Comment: I have searched as `python multiple if statements "and" condition best practices` and found many junky fundamental definitions. Finally I have found how `all` and `any` helps to define multiple if statements for `and` and `or` condition. Thanks!

Comment: Very enjoyable solution, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're passing in strings rather than integers, try casting the arguments to integers:

```
def example(arg1, arg2, arg3):
     if int(arg1) == 1 and int(arg2) == 2 and int(arg3) == 3:
          print("Example Text")
```

(Edited to emphasize I'm not asking for clarification; I was trying to be diplomatic in my answer. )

Comment: This should be a comment.

Answer (score 2):

Might be a bit odd or bad practice but this is one way of going about it.

```
(arg1, arg2, arg3) = (1, 2, 3)

if (arg1 == 1)*(arg2 == 2)*(arg3 == 3):
    print('Example.')
```

Anything multiplied by 0 == 0. If any of these conditions fail then it evaluates to false.

Comment: Why would you prefer this over the obvious?

Answer (score 0):

I am a little late to the party but I thought I'd share a way of doing it, if you have identical types of conditions, i.e. checking if all, any or at given amount of A_1=A_2 and B_1=B_2, this can be done in the following way:

```
cond_list_1=["1","2","3"]
cond_list_2=["3","2","1"]
nr_conds=1

if len([True for i, j in zip(cond_list_1, cond_list_2) if i == j])>=nr_conds:
    print("At least " + str(nr_conds) + " conditions are fullfilled")

if len([True for i, j in zip(cond_list_1, cond_list_2) if i == j])==len(cond_list_1):
    print("All conditions are fullfilled")
```

This means you can just change in the two initial lists, at least for me this makes it easier.

Comment: horribly verbose and unreadable.  See the answer above that uses the "all" method for a clean way to implement this

Comment: Yeah except the all statement does not allow for a specific number of conditions. Making it horribly simplistic and downright useless. Not to mention that you are not able to change the lists without changing the code, again simplistic and non-flexible. But thanks for your input

Comment: Please give an example, because I see no difference between what you have and what the example above it does.  Both can change the conditions at runtime and I would think that needing a threshold number of conditions rather than all to be a rare occurrence, and not what the OP asked for!  To duplicate your "at least one", use any() instead of all()

Comment: Neither of the answers can change the number of conditions, they can change the conditions themselves but not the number of them.

Comment: You can't add to the condition list?

Comment: Yes you can, but you are not able to e.g. change the number of conditions to return true if 3 out of 5 conditions are met.