# Multiple IF statements in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement

I am trying to print the content in a specific cell. i know the cells i want to check before extracting the content to the output. i am using multiple IF statements for this :

```
if lineCount == 5:
    if line[0]:
        print line[0], 'A5'
        OPfound = 1
        break
    if line[1]:
        print line[1], 'B5'
        OPfound = 1
        break
if lineCount == 4:
    if line[0]:
        print line[0], 'A4'
        OPfound = 1
        break
    if line[1]:
        print line[1],'B4'
        OPfound = 1
        break
```

The output is in the form :- extracted content, cell number

what i am trying to do is first check if there is any content in A5 - if there is content then extract it...else check for content in B5 - if there is content then extract it...else check content in A4

i am getting output for B5 and A4...but NOT FOR A5

also how do i check content in B4 ONLY if there is no content in A5,B5 and A4...

Comment: Please extend your code to include information about what `line` and `lineCount` are. Also, your indentation is way off.

Comment: What is a "cell?"

Comment: I hope your indentation has been messed up when you pasted it, even though it does work.

Comment: You could `print "A{}".format(linecount)`, by the way to condense some code

Comment: Have you done any research into what `break` actually does, or into more details of the `if` statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`break` doesn't let you leave `if` clauses, if that's what you are indeed attempting to break out of.  The trick here is to remove the `break` statements and replace your second `if`s with `elif`s like so:

```
if lineCount == 5:
    if line[0]:
        print line[0],'A5'
        OPfound = 1
    elif line[1]:
        print line[1],'B5'
        OPfound = 1
if lineCount == 4:
    if line[0]:
        print line[0],'A4'
        OPfound = 1
    elif line[1]:
        print line[1],'B4'
        OPfound = 1
```

This way you are only running through the second `if` statement in each lineCount clause if the first one failed, not every time.

Comment: this is giving me almost what i asked for...but if there is content in A5 i dont want A4 to be read...right now i am getting output for both A4 and A5...what will be the fix for this?

Comment: @safwan Just make the second outside if statement an elif: e.g. `elif lineCount==4:`

Comment: elif means, if the previous if or elif condition wasn't true (and only if it wasn't) then check this one. elif stands for else if. There is also `else`, which covers any conditions you didn't include. Putting if statements within if statements is a form of nesting (nested if statements).

Answer (score 17):

Darian Moody has a nice solution to this challenge in his [blog post](https://www.djm.org.uk/posts/python-multiple-line-conditions-and-all-builtin/):

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = True

rules = [a == 1,
         b == 2,
         c == True]

if all(rules):
    print("Success!")
```

The all() method returns `True` when all elements in the given iterable are true. If not, it returns `False`.

You can read a *little* more about it in the python docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#all) and more information and examples [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/all).

(I also answered the similar question with this info here - [How to have multiple conditions for one if statement in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36757965/how-to-have-multiple-conditions-for-one-if-statement-in-python/50656647#50656647))

Answer (score 2):

First off, you don't end a Python code block with `break`. Python ends a code block when it sees that you have indented back, like this:

```
if condition: //or any other statement that needs a block
    //code goes here
//end of block
```

The `break` statement is used to terminate the innermost loop it can find. If you're running that code under a loop, the `break` statement might produce some serious bugs.

Anyways, there is a much more conventional way of testing something for multiple conditions. Your current setup without the `break` statements should work, but I suggest you use an `if...elif...else` statement. Here's the format:

```
if condition:
    //run if true
elif condition:
    //run if first expression was false, and this is true
elif condition:
    //run if second expression was false, and this is true

... (you get the idea)

else:
    //run if all other expressions are false
```

Keep in mind that after Python has found an expression that is true in such a statement, then it will run the corresponding block of code and ignore all other blocks.

Hope this helps!