# How to populate more than one outcome with while loop and if else function

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

I'm a new python learner who is trying to figure out how to populate **multiple results based on if then conditions** in python. I'm unsure how to utilize while loop function in order for me to pull multiple results.

For example,

```
    if high >= (.20):
        print('High level is Red')
    elif med  >= (.20):
        print('Medium level is Red')
    elif low  >= (.20):
        print('Low level is Red')
    elif grand_total  >= (.20):
        print('Grand Total is Red')    
    else:
        print('None')
```

As you can see, the above statement gives only one out of five options. But I'm trying to pull out **ALL OF CORRECT conditions.** Can someone please give me an advice? Thank you in advance!!

Also, I can't use for loop function either because they are all separate dataframes. Or is there any other way?

Comment: one of the answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41032495/multiple-if-statements-in-python#50656735

Answer (score 1):

you can combine all condition together with `and` and check if result is obtain. or instead of `elif` you can use if condition only. and save result together.

with `and`

```
if high >= (.20) and med  >= (.20) and low  >= (.20) and grand_total  >= (.20):
    print('High level is Red')
    print('Medium level is Red')
    print('Low level is Red')
    print('Grand Total is Red')    
else:
    print('None')
```

without `elif` condition, only using `if`

```
if high >= (.20):
    print('High level is Red')
if med  >= (.20):
    print('Medium level is Red')
if low  >= (.20):
    print('Low level is Red')
if grand_total  >= (.20):
    print('Grand Total is Red')    
if not ( high >= (.20)) and  not (med  >= (.20)) and not (low  >= (.20)) and not (grand_total  >= (.20)):
    print('None')
```

Answer (score 1):

The most simple solution is to replace the "elif" statements with their own individual "if" statements, then have the last "else" be "if grand_total < 0.2"

i.e.

```
    if high >= (.20):
        print('High level is Red')
    if med  >= (.20):
        print('Medium level is Red')
    if low  >= (.20):
        print('Low level is Red')
    if grand_total  >= (.20):
        print('Grand Total is Red')    
    if grand_total < (.20) and low < (.20) and high < (.20) and med < (.20):
        print('None')
```

and if you'd like to use a loop, you can use a dictionary and flag to get it to work:

```
flag = True
d = {
    'High': high,
    'Medium': med,
    'Low': low,
    'Grand Total': grand_total
}
for i in d:
    if d[i] >= (.20):
        flag = False
        print('{0} level is Red'.format(i))
if flag: print('None')
```