# Why is line 8 in my basic calculator not working as intended?

Tags: python, calculator

The code I've written is:

```
while Operator != "+" and "-" and "*" and "^" and "/" and "/+" and "v-":
    Operator = input("Please write an operator (+, -, *, ^, /, /+, v-): ")
```

I intended it to only ask "Please write an operator (+, -, *, ^, /, /+, v-): " if you have not typed one but my code only seems to work if you use specifically +. -, * etc. don't seem to register as an operator for whatever reason. I tried looking for a .isoperator method but that didn't exist, I tried changing the ands for ors and that didn't work, I tried using while not Operator == instead of while Operator != and nothing worked (if possible, don't recommend code that's too complicated, I only have 1 day of experience in programming as a whole).

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36757965/how-to-have-multiple-conditions-for-one-if-statement-in-python

Comment: Also, please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I think I got the edit right... but there is no line 8. Edit as needed!

Answer (score 0):

You want to know if a value is in a set of values... so use a set:

```
_op_values = {"+", "-", "*", "^", "/", "/+", "v-"}
_op_values_prompt = ", ".join(_op_values)
Operator = ""
while Operator not in _op_values:
    Operator = input(f"Please write an operator ({_op_values_prompt}): ")
```

Comment: @Someone - It would be useful to go through the standard python tutorial to get familiar with the language. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html